# two pages of canvas linked in python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, root

in my GUI i used canvas I want my program to be linked two page one to write 'welcome' and press a button that move it to the program page..
I have tried to add Next function, but I'm lost

```
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

MyImage = PhotoImage(file='222.png')
MyImage1 = PhotoImage(file='66.png')
#the welcome page
def Next():
    global myCanvas, myCanvas2
    myCanvas2.delete(all)
    myCanvas = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0).pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    myCanvas.create_image(0,0,image= MyImage, anchor='nw')
    #Button for location
    SaveLoc = Button(root, width=15, bg='#EDB491',fg='white', text='Choose location', command = openLocation)
    myCanvas.create_window(145,154, anchor='nw', window=SaveLoc)
    #Error message of locatino
    LocError = myCanvas.create_text(200,187, text='You must select a location',fill='#E1B5C6', font=('jost', 10))


#File location
Folder_Name =""
def openLocation():
    global Folder_Name
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if len(Folder_Name) > 1:
        myCanvas.itemconfig(LocError,text=Folder_Name, fill='green')
    else:
        myCanvas.itemconfig(LocError,text='Please Choose Folder!!',fill='red')


myCanvas2 = Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
myCanvas2.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
CanvasImage=myCanvas2.create_image(0,0,image= MyImage1, anchor='nw')
#Download button
Down = Button(root, width=10, bg='#EDB491',fg='white', text='go', command= Next)
DownW=myCanvas2.create_window(162,300, anchor='nw', window=Down)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you get error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't know what you try to do but maybe you could use `Label` to display image and you could put this `Label` and `Button` in `Frame` instead of `Canvas`

Comment: where do you have `myCanvas.pack()` to display it ?

Comment: I know how to do it with frame but in this program I must use canvas. I put `myCanvas.pack()` in Next function.

Comment: I have two canvases `myCanvas` with its button and label its in `def Next():`  and `myCanvas2` outside and I wanna link them. So when I press button `Down` in `myCanvas2` its will disappear and `myCanvas` will appear.

Comment: if you want to disapper one canvas then better use `myCanvas2.destroy()` because using `.delete(all)` you only remove elements from canvas but `myCanvas2` still exists in window and it has height `300` and new canvas is 300px below. But I would use only one canvas and put new image to old canvas instead of creating new one.

Comment: That's amazing!!! its work. And yeah I tried to use just one canvas, but it doesn't really work with me. Any way I'm really thankful.

Comment: in answer I put full working code with single `Canvas` and with other changes. You can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was hundreds times on Stackoverflow.

You have the most common mistake

```
 variable = Widget.pack()
```

It assings `None` to `variable` because `pack()`/`grid()`/`place()` returns `None`

You have to do it in two steps

```
 variable = Widget
 variable.pack()
```

---

And you have

```
 myCanvas = Canvas(...).pack(...)
```

so it assign `None` to `myCanvas` and later `myCanvas.create_image` means

```
 None.create_image(...)
```

and you get error

```
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_image'
```

You need

```
 myCanvas = Canvas(...)
 myCanvas.pack(...)
```

---

**EDIT:**

My version with single `Canvas` so I don't need another `pack()`

I made other changes - ie. I use `anchor="center"` to put button and text in center.

BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guidefor Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pp-0008/)

---

```
import os
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8 `import *` is not preferred
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names) (PEP8: all functions before main part)

def next_image():
    # no need `global my_canvas` because I don't try to assign `=` to `my_canvas`
    global save_loc  # PEP8: `global` in separed lines
    global loc_error
    
    my_canvas.delete('all')
    
    my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=my_image_2, anchor='nw')
    
    #Button for location
    save_loc = tk.Button(root, width=15, bg='#EDB491', fg='white', text='Choose location', command=open_location)
    my_canvas.create_window(200, 200-20, anchor='center', window=save_loc)
    
    #Error message of locatino
    loc_error = my_canvas.create_text(200, 200+20, anchor='center', text='You must select a location', fill='#E1B5C6', font=('jost', 10))

def open_location():
    global folder_name    
    
    folder_name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    
    if folder_name:
        my_canvas.itemconfig(loc_error, text=folder_name, fill='green')
    else:
        my_canvas.itemconfig(loc_error, text='Please Choose Folder!!', fill='red')

# --- main --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# folder with running code - to create full path to images
APP_HOME = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('APP_HOME:', APP_HOME)

# File location  # (PEP8: one space after `#`)
folder_name = ""

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
#root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # don't need it if I don't use `grid()`

my_image_1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(APP_HOME, 'lenna.png'))
my_image_2 = tk.PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(APP_HOME, 'lenna.png'))
    
my_canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=350, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

canvas_image = my_canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=my_image_1, anchor='nw')

# Download button
down_button = tk.Button(root, width=10, bg='#EDB491', fg='white', text='GO', command=next_image)
my_canvas.create_window(200, 200, anchor='center', window=down_button)

root.mainloop()
```

---

I use image from Wikipedia: [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna)

lenna.png

[image]